# How did we know that this distribution is triangular and symmetric about 0?

Tags: probability-distributions

[image]

I know that this distribution is symmetrical about y axis since f(-x)=f(x) but how did we know that it was symmetrical about 0 an dthat it is a triangular distribution?
Since I know that a triangular distribution has the following expression:
[image]

And why did we infer from the symmetry that E(x)=μ=0 without computing any integral?

Comment: "symmetrical about $y$ axis" is the same as saying "symmetrical about $0$" since the $y$-axis is the line $x=0$; equivalently, saying $f(-x)=f(x)$ is the same as saying $f(0-x)=f(0+x)$, which demonstrates symmetry about $0$

Answer (score 1):

when $x$ is positive, $x \in (0, \tau)$, the graph is a line with negative slope.

Now, flip it along the $y$-axis, you get an increasing line.

Together, you get a triangle.